# VBA Selecting parts of multible columns

Tags: excel, vba

So I want to copy lets say Rows 5-15 from Columns B,E,G, from one worksheet to another.

So far I have tried it like this

```
Sheets("Table1").Select
Range("B5:B15,E5:E15,G5:G15").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Table2").Select
Range("B4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

That's the concept.
I have much more Columns to copy and when doing it it doesn't work as I want like this

```
Sheets("Table1").Select
Range("CT5:CT15,CB5:CB15,CN5:CN15,DJ5:DJ15,DL5:DL15,E5:E15,AP5:AP15,CU5:CU15,AZ5:AZ15,AX5:AX15,CZ5:CZ15,CV5:CV15,AR5:AR15,AM5:AM15,Q5:Q15,CG5:CG15,AC5:AC15,R5:R15,CY5:CY15,G5:G15,Z5:Z15,C5:C15,DP5:DP15,Y5:Y15,X5:X15,CJ5:CJ15,DQ5:DQ15,CQ5:CQ15,AK5:AK15,AJ5:AJ15,BA5:BA15,BQ5:BQ15,CL5:CL15,BH5:BH15,DO5:DO15,AB5:AB15,CH5:CH15,CK5:CK15,P5:P15,CI5:CI15").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Table2").Select
Range("B4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Is there a way to streamline? To say I wand Row 5-15 from all these columns?

Thank you

Comment: Something like this: `Worksheets("Table1").Range("B5:B15,E5:E15,G5:G15").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Table2").Range("B4")`.  Not sure how you want it streamlined or why it's time consuming or prone to errors.

Comment: `Select` only activates the visual UI selection, but AFAICT anything you can do with the visual selection you can do with a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) -- an object referencing one or more cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Intersect to get the range to copy.

```
Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim rngCols As Range
Dim rngRows As Range

    With Sheets("Tabelle1")
        Set rngCols = .Range("B:B, E:E, G:G")
        Set rngRows = .Rows("5:15")
    End With

    Set rngCopy = Intersect(rngCols, rngRows)

    rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A4")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Non-Contiguous Columns Range

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyMultiColumns()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Table1"
    Const sRows As String = "5:15"
    Const sColsList As String = "" _
        & "C,E,G,P,Q,R,X,Y,Z," _
        & "AB,AC,AJ,AK,AM,AP,AR,AX,AZ," _
        & "BA,BH,BQ," _
        & "CB,CG,CH,CI,CJ,CK,CL,CN,CQ,CT,CU,CV,CY,CZ," _
        & "DJ,DL,DO,DP,DQ"
    
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Table2"
    Const dFirst As String = "B4"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sCols)
        If srg Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = sws.Columns(sCols(n))
        Else
            Set srg = Union(srg, sws.Columns(sCols(n)))
        End If
    Next n

    Set srg = Intersect(srg, sws.Rows(sRows))
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    srg.Copy dws.Range(dFirst)
    
End Sub
```